# Translating Stata xtmelogit to R glmer (lme4) package

Tags: r, stata, lme4, mixed-models

I try to recalculate exactly  published Stata code in R. In the first step I exported the same dataset from Stata and Imported it in R. Nevertheless I am fighting with errors in my code.
What am I doing wrong?

Original Stata Code:

```
xtmelogit redpref1 c.incomedif c.incomedif#c.forpop forpop i.year if (brncntr==1) || country:
```

My Approach in R was:

```
dataset <- dataset%>%
  filter(brncntr==1) %>%
  mutate(c.incomedif = factor(incomedif))%>%
  mutate(c.forpop = factor(forpop)) %>%
  mutate(i.year = as.integer(year))) 

library(lme4) 
    logit <- glmer(redpref1~ c.incomedif+ i.year|country,family=binomial,rueda4, nAGQ=0L)
    summary(logit)
```

This approach generates an error as follows:

```
Error in if (ctrl$npt > (2 * n + 1)) warning("Setting npt > 2 * length(par) + 1 is not recommended.") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In (n + 1L) * (n + 2L) : NAs produced by integer overflow
>
```

Comment: Maybe try the default `nAGQ=1L` instead of setting it to 0?

Comment: Also your model formula in `glmer` isn’t entirely correct; the random effects need to be specified in parentheses i.e. `redpref1 ~ c.incomedif + i.year  + (1 | country)`